# CapacitorJS, make iOS status bar non-transparent

Tags: ios, swift, capacitor

I have an CapacitorJS application with following `capacitor.config.ts`

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli'

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  ...
  ios: {
    contentInset: 'always',
  },
}

export default config
```

At the top of the page I have a nice screen with white status bar background like this:

[image]

But when I scroll down page content mixes with status bar. It looks bad.

[image]

How can I make my status bar always white (or black if the user has black theme iOS settings).

Comment: In iOS apps you don't have an opaque status bar for a few years now. You have to provide the background yourself in the layout of the screen.

Comment: @Alistra and how it could be done? Just by placing a `div` with `position: fixed` and negative `top`, like `top: -20px; width: 100%`?